# How to change the code on runtime after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I am trying to change code of Java script on the fly.
I am using chrome. My problem is how do I keep the changes after I do refresh because for now  I am setting break point before the change and change the code and save it and run it. But when refreshing the page it it return to the original one.
How can I load it with me changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Save the changes in the actual JavaScript file, instead of in the debugger

Comment: This file isn't on local , I am getting this file from server some where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make changes within the debugger console, instead change your code in your underlaying *.js-file and hit refresh.

Comment: That's... exactly what I said.

Comment: can you explane how to to that?

Comment: the problem is when I refresh my page I am getting the original file. can you write a way to get my changes? please write details how can be done?

Comment: If you don't own the original file and if it is not stored on your server, that's impossible. Download the *.js, put it on your server, reference it, edit it - locally.